# Trying to replicate a particular row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I am trying to duplicate a value at a particular indexed row and insert this new duplicated row below the original row in the dataframe.

I have the following code:

```
indexnumber = random.randrange(datafile.shape[0])
newdf = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(datafile.iloc[indexnumber].values, 2, axis=0))
print(newdf)
```

I want to randomly pick one reaction time and duplicate it, next to the original item, so that if the list is [2,3,4] and the random number is 1, the resulting list should be [2,3,3,4].

I would be so grateful for any help!

The first 10 rows of the Datafile dataframe:

```
print(datafile.head(10))
```

```
     0
0  307
1  209
2  371
3  266
4  372
5  298
6  338
7  302
8  264
9  247
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with a custom array as repeater:

```
# set up repeater array with 1s
n = np.ones(len(df))
# pick one random value to be 2
n[np.random.randint(0, len(df))] = 2

# reindex
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(n)]
```

Example output:

```
     0
0  307
1  209
2  371
3  266  # duplicated
3  266  #
4  372
5  298
6  338
7  302
8  264
9  247
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway!! - so the line: out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(n)], will go through each index in 'df' and duplicate it 'n' number of times and then print the output of the final dataframe?

Comment: Exactly, except for the "print", it rather *returns* a new DataFrame ;)